# C++ Comparing string to 0 using == operator?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string A1;
  cin>>A1;
  if(A1==0)
   {
     cout<<"Success!";
   }
  else
   {
     cout<<"Failure!";
   }
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Beginner in C++. I`m trying to compare the value of a string keyed in to 0 using the == operator. Above is my sample of code. How do I solve this problem in the simplest manner? Thank you.

Comment: probably you meant "0".

Comment: Not sure of your intention... comparing to `"0"` or comparing to `0`

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want to check if the string `"0"` was entered? Or check for NULL?

Comment: It should be `#include <string>`, not `#include <string.h>`

Comment: For example the user enter the value zero, 0 for A1, it gets compared to the (A1==0) and goes into the if {} part of the code?

Comment: @Theolodis: That doesn't make sense. There's no variable here which can be `NULL`.

Comment: @MSalters thats why I asked, because checking `A1==0` actually would check for `NULL` if `A1` was of type `char[]`

Comment: @Theolodis: Even if it was a `char[N]` it still couldn't be `NULL`, so  it still wouldn't make sense to compare A1 to NULL.

Comment: I am totally aware of that, but I wanted to find out if the OP did. Because a correct answer would be different depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing `if(A1 == "0")`. The C++ `std::string` class *overloads* the `==` operator to allow this.

To check if the string is empty, write `if (A1.empty())` or `if (!A1.size())`.  I prefer the second formulation as it's consistent with other C++ standard library objects.

Personally I prefer to use the `compare` method on `std::string` instead. This makes your code more readable by other developers (e.g. Java developers would hate to see `==` in this context).

Comment: okay, it works for now, I was using int data type for most of my program, then when I cin>> an alphabet, the program gets bugged and my loop failed, was trying to change all the data type to string, doesn`t know it will work or nt but thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a strongly typed language. `0` by itself is a number. `"0"` is a string literal. There are functions which can do conversions, eg. `std::stoi` (String to Integer) and `std::to_string` (Lots of things to string), though.

So you have quite a few possible solutions here, to get the types equal. There's no real best solution for such a simplified case.